# Prolog date_time_stamp

Tags: prolog

Trying to make a rule within prolog, which would ask if any messages where sent between 2 individuals (where both individuals can be the recipient or the sender of the message) before a given date. After calling whether it is true or not, it is to print all the logs where the 2 users have exchanged messages before the given time.

so far i thought,

```
msgbefore(X,Y,D) :-
    message(X,Y,D1),
    date_time_stamp(D),
    date_time_stamp(D1),
    D1 < D, 
message(Y,X,D1),
    date_time_stamp(D),
    date_time_stamp(D1),
    D1 < D.
```

database consists of:

```
message(sonny,robert,'2012-05-12').
message(robert,sarah,'2012-05-12').
message(julie,mary,'2012-05-12').
message(fred,nayna,'2012-05-13').
message(fred,daniel,'2012-05-14').
message(nayna,lucia,'2012-05-15').
```

please help,

Comment: this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872512/can-someone-help-me-with-prolog-please

Comment: i have search all across the internet, and yes i have found multiple post revolving around the same task, however, every time i try to use their solutions, the rule is found to be incorrect. Ive made my own post due to the fact that the link u sent me is now a closed post with no given solution, and all other post have not seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just an hint: [date_time_stamp](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=date_time_stamp/2) requires 2 arguments and is rather difficult to use, but since your dates are provided as atoms in standard form, you can directly compare them. For instance

```
1 ?- message(A,B,Date),Date @< '2012-05-13'.
A = sonny,
B = robert,
Date = '2012-05-12' ;
...
```

Comment: well for the task at hand, im supposed to make the prolog software look through the large attached database, and compare all messages sent between the two indiviudals, i am no supposed to declare what the date or the messages within the data base are. is it possible to do this same rule like this?

1 ?- message(A,B,Date),Date @< D1.
A = sonny,
B = robert,
Date = '2012-05-12' ;

Comment: @user3155657 it's unclear what the query is that you are trying to solve. CapelliC gave a solution to what your `msgbefore` predicate appears to be trying to do. Perhaps you could update your problem and indicate clearly what you want to be able to type in and what kind of results are you expecting.

Comment: @user3155657: a possible definition `msgbefore(X,Y,D) :- message(X,Y,D1), @D1 @< Date.`

Comment: sry if i didnt make it clear, ive been tasked to create a rule within prolog, which would check if it is true or not that 2 inidivduals had been exchanging messages before a set time. with this, i would ask the prolog somthing along the lines of msgbefore(sonny,robert,'2012-06-12'). from that, the software is to look through the whole database (where i have only placed a small example of the large database) and declare if that query was true or not.From there, i have also been asked to print all message logs where exchanging of messages from the inidiviudals where before that time.

Comment: @user3155657: Sorry, I put a bug in the comment above:Date should be D. Is that bug to give you problems ?

Comment: sry no matter what, the reply is considered false.

Comment: @user3155657: how do you load the database ? you should put those facts in a file.pl and do `?- [file].`

Comment: if it helps i can show a larger portion of the database for more of an idea of how the message log looks

Comment: the database is in a .pl file and is directly opened into SWI-prolog, after, an rule.pl file is consulted into the software that defines the rules im attaching it

Comment: so far when i add a query this shows up no matter what
'1 ?- msgbefore(sonny,robert,'2012-06-12').
false.'

Comment: @user3155657: must be something banal. What about if you query '?-msgbefore(A,B,'3000-01-01').

Comment: ok, i finally fixed it, sry it was my own silly mistake where i used < isntead of >. thank you for all the help, the @> actually was very helpful to use, but may i ask, how would i print all messages from before the date i asked in the query?

Comment: @user3155657: see forall/2 and findall/3. Browsing some other questions could help you.

Comment: ok ty for all, is there a way to close the call this post solved?

Comment: @user3155657: do you mean accepting the (incomplete) answer ?