# Creating a list to return Date(s)

Tags: prolog

I currently have a database which consists of a list of people, who they've sent a message to and the date which the message was sent. See the following:

```
message(allan, steve, 2013-09-03). 
message(nayna, jane, 2013-09-03). 
message(steve, jane, 2013-09-04). 
message(steve, allan, 2013-09-04). 
message(mark, martin, 2013-09-04). 
message(martin, steve, 2013-09-04). 
message(allan, martin, 2013-09-05).
```

For one of my tasks, I need to create a rule which returns a list of all dates of when person 1 (P1) and person 2 (P2) have exchanged messages until date (D).

So far I have the following:

```
message(P1,P2,Date),D=Date,print([D]); message(P2,P1,Date),D=Date,print([D]).
```

I need a rule that will return just a list of all the dates without having to enter `;` every time.

I know this rule needs fixing so any help/advise is appreciated!

Comment: Are you with the NSA?

Comment: Some related posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895795/prolog-date-time-stamp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886736/how-to-create-a-network-link-tree
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847647/need-prolog-help-please

Comment: Note that `D=Date,print([D])` is equivalent to `print([Date])` since you aren't using `D` any other way. Also, are you allowed to use `findall/3` or `setof/3`?

Comment: +1 for a cleanly formulated question.

Comment: okay thanks! and what is the difference between using findall/3 and setof/3? We can use either, but we'd need to be able to understand and explain it @mbratch

Comment: `findall/3` will put every solution into the output list, whether there are duplicates or not. `setof/3` will do that, but then eliminate duplicates and sort them (via `@<`). @WillNess is using `setof/3` as part of his solution.

Comment: will findall/3 sort the output list via @< as well then? and thankyou! starting to understand now @mbratch

Comment: `findall` does not eliminate duplicates and it does not sort.

Comment: Hi, I rolled back your last edit. It changes the original question too much, invalidating the answer(s); and it doesn't make much sense in itself. Did someone else use your credentials? The way to ask new question on SO, is to post new question. :) If you need some more clarifications, you can edit them in, *adding* to the post, not erasing it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended the shown code to be a body of your rule,

```prolog
my_rule(P1,P2,D):-
  message(P1,P2,Date),D=Date,print([D]); message(P2,P1,Date),D=Date,print([D]).
```

Of course for dates *before* a given date we need `@<` instead of `=`:

```prolog
my_rule(P1,P2,D):-
  message(P1,P2,Date),D@<Date,print([D]); message(P2,P1,Date),D@<Date,print([D]).
```

But there's a lot of code replication there; we need to abstract over *something*, obviously:

```prolog
my_rule(P1,P2,D):-
  message_between(P1,P2,Date),D@<Date,print([D]).

message_between(P1,P2,Date):- message(P1,P2,Date) ; message(P2,P1,Date).
```

This code is still buggy. Which date is given to us? Which date we find? Which we want to print out?

```prolog
my_rule(P1,P2,D):-
  message_between(P1,P2,Date),D @>= Date,print([Date]).
```

This is about right. Now we can get to the second part of your question – you don't want to "press `;`" all the time, to get the solutions one by one.

First, notice that you don't *get* a solution right now from your predicate, it gets printed by it, instead. The fix:

```prolog
my_rule(P1,P2,Dtop,Date):-
  message_between(P1,P2,Date),Dtop @>= Date.
```

Now, when `my_rule/4` succeeds, it instantiates its 4th argument to a date of message exchange between the two given people, if it were not later than `Dtop` date (its 3rd argument).

To collect them all, you need to use the built-in predicate [`setof`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof/3), as was hinted to you in the comments by mbratch.

```prolog
all_dates(P1,P2,Dtop,DatesList):-
   setof( Date, my_rule(P1,P2,Dtop,Date), .... ).
```

This will work if all the three first arguments to the predicate `all_dates` are given fully (i.e. are instantiated to ground terms), when it is called. Do replace the dots with a meaningful entry. Either guess, or - better - read the documentation for `setof` and [`findall`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3).

There's one discrepancy here still. What if there were no messages exchanged, at all, for a given combination of people and date? The rule as given above will fail. Perhaps you'd like it to succeed with an empty list as a solution instead. Can you make the necessary adjustments? Use the following skeleton:

```prolog
rule_suceeds( ..., DatesList):-
   /*... a rule that instantiates `DatesList` ...*/ -> true ; ... = [] .
```

Comment: so would I insert all rules as shown above (Except the first block of code) into SWI Prolog and obviously replace P1, P2 and Date with actual data @WillNess

Comment: I'm not familiar with prolog at all! but that has helped me @WillNess

Comment: and would I replace the dots with 'Date'? :s @WillNess

Comment: all `my_rule` variants except the last one are buggy.  You insert them into a file, and then "consult" this file from SWI. One way is to save  the code in file "code.pl" and then from SWI, at the prompt, type `[code].` (enter). Or you can type `[user]` and then copy-paste the code into the secondary prompt that opens there. -- about the dots: no, not `Date`. What else is there, that you want (hint) to instantiate (i.e. set it to some value)? We instantiate logvars either by using them in some predicate which instantiates some of its arguments (e.g. `setof`) or directly by e.g. `DateList = []`.

Comment: Will Ness, Very nice breakdown, but what do you mean by the symbol"@" in D@  ?.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 `@<` is a [built-in term comparison operator](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(@%3C)/2). e.g.: `1 ?- D=a,E=b,D@<E.` ==> 
`D = a,
E = b.`. `D@<E` parses as `D @< E`.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 ok, here `D` is a given date, `Date` is found from the database and checked that is before `D`. And you shouldn't omit parts of definitions, it is just confusing: the full rule is: `my_rule(P1,P2,D):- message_between(P1,P2,Date),D @>= Date,print([Date]).`. Apparently, it finds and prints (one by one) dates of messages exchanged between people `P1` and `P2`, not later than date `D` (all three must be given by the user).